# Как вывести список без ненужных квадратных скобок, запятых и ненужной строки

Tags: python

Если что код поворачивает список на 90 градусов

```py
o = [input() for _ in range(int(input()))]


def turn(a):
    _list = zip(*a[::-1])
    return [list(e) for e in _list]


o = turn(o)
[print(i, sep="", end='\n') for i in o]
```

Ввод:

```
1 2
2 1
```

Вывод:

```
['2', '1']
[' ', ' '] # ненужная строка 
['1', '2']
```

Правильный вывод:

```
2 1
1 2
```

Comment: 1) Укажите, что вводите, хотя бы. У меня так вывод в одну строку. 2) Судя по всему, код чужой, попробовали бы сами вывод исправить, да спросить о том, что не получается.

Comment: пробовал, не получилось

Comment: как правило, такие ответы дают, когда не пробовали. но дело ваше, может, кто и ответит.

Comment: Если что, ненужная  строка появляется уже при повороте.

Comment: спасибо, я этого даже не заметил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если все таки разбить строки на слова, то тогда в вашем коде надо будет изменить лишь первую и последнюю строки:

```
o = [input().split() for i in range(int(input()))]
def turn(a):
    list1 = zip(*a[::-1])
    return [list(e) for e in list1]
o = list(turn(o))
[print(' '.join(i)) for i in o]
```

Опять таки если чуть-чуть подчистить код:

```
turn = lambda a: zip(*a[::-1])

o = [input().split() for i in range(int(input()))]
o = turn(o)

print(*[' '.join(i) for i in o], sep='\n')
```

Comment: А, ну да, можно ж было сплит сделать

Comment: Извините, а можете подсказать что такое zip. Я просто не так давно занялся питоном, но за код большое спасибо!

Comment: в первой строчке

Comment: то что после zip срез, я знаю

Comment: `zip` объединяет итерируемые объекты формируя новый итерируемый объект - например список [1, 2, 3] и ['a', 'b', 'c'] zip превратит в [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]

Answer (score 3):

Пустая строка формируется из знаков пробела, которые вы подаете на вход. Если воспользоваться вот так, то пробельных символов не будет. `zip` формирует из всех символов кортежи. В том числе и пробелов

```py
# ввод 
2
12
21
```

а для печати можно использовать так

```py
for i in o:
  print(*i)
```

вывод

```
2 1
1 2
```

Удалить пробелы можно так

```py
def turn(a):
    a = [i.replace(" ", "") for i in a]
    list1 = zip(*a[::-1])
    return [list(e) for e in list1]
```

Comment: а никак нельзя убрать всё же пробелы, но за код большое спасибо

Comment: @user504877 Обновил ответ

Comment: спасибо, за код с пробелами

Comment: точнее вывод без пробелов